# Can we remove these tag synonyms for "logic"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

```
Tag synonyms for logic
The following tags will be remapped to logic:
reasoning, contradiction and conditionals
```

I would advocate removing all of these synonyms, as they function better as independent, specific concepts. I don't have enough rep to suggest a tag synonym edit.